# Table of Content javascript input

Tags: javascript, json, tableofcontents

I want to create a simple table of content for my project.
I tried using this library:

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EnLwb/

and giving a sample json input without success.

this is my json:

```
"{"0":{"text":"text0","id":0},"1":{"text":"text1","id":1}}"
```

**Problem**

I'm trying to replace $("article h3") with

```
var = $(jsonInput)
```

coming from HTML call. The result is blank - nothing is displayed.

Comment: And what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: I don't know how to change the javascript to work with outside json variable (or even internal) in order to produce the ToC. I want to pass a simple key:value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what I was missing:

```
var dictionary = {
    "data":[
        {"id":"0","name":"ABC","text":"PQR"},
        {"id":"1","name":"DEF","text":"PQR"}
    ]
};

dictionary.data.forEach(function(item){
  el = $(item);
  title = el.attr("text");
  link = "#" + el.attr("id");
```

So in order to replace html element of the code I needed:
1) to iterate over the json array
2) replace jquery function

```
   title = el.text();
```

with

```
el.attr("text");
```